# Source could not be found Java

Tags: java, error-handling, jvm

I am working on my finals project on Java with the Eclipse platform. I try and create a new object (Store in that case) and the program fails to locate the class it seems.

```
Store s = new Store("Store" , storeId);
```

After debugging that line, I bump into this error:

> JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]

In addition, a window pops up saying source not found, asking me to find the source. The source is marked as the src file of the project so that is not the case. In addition, tried to enter "System.Exit(0)" as mentioned in questions before me, but that failed as well.

Comment: The code isn't really important for it since it fails to locate the file.
Anyways, basically I try and create a new store (which leads to another class) as so:

Store s = new Store("Store" , storeId)

And the program doesn't even go into the class, pointing to the fact that it lost its way to it.

Comment: What is `Store`? I don't get it, how are we supposed to help you? There's little detail and code to find your mistake.

Comment: Store, as I said, is an object.
As I mentioned, the problem is not with the code, but with the way the program tries to open certain classes. I cannot include Store since its a 400 rows class, also pointing to the fact that the problem is not the code which worked before.

Comment: Why do you think it might be maltfunctioning? Is there any way you could work around these problems?